# extracting specifiv values from pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a data in pandas data frame column as below:

```
[2, 4]
[3, 4]
[1, 4]
[0, 0]
```

I want the data to be in the form of

```
col_1  col_2
2      4
3      4
1      4
0      0
```

Can anyone help me how can I get the data in the above form.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.tolist()` to do this pretty easily if the lists all have the same number of elements

```
import pandas as pd   
df = pd.DataFrame({'val1': [[2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 4], [0, 0]]})   

df[['col_1', 'col_2']] = pd.DataFrame(df.val1.tolist())
     val1  col_1  col_2
0  [2, 4]      2      4
1  [3, 4]      3      4
2  [1, 4]      1      4
3  [0, 0]      0      0
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thank you ALollz

Answer (score 1):

ALollz gave a better answer, but given the title about extracting specific values, here's a more direct and illustrative (but less efficient) method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["cur"] = [[2,4],[3,4],[1,4],[0,0]]
print(df) # This is what you have

# You can access elements by df[<column>][<row>][<list index>]
# This is looping across all rows of the "cur" column, and pulling out
#    the values at the 0th and 1st index.
df["col_1"] = [pair[0] for pair in df["cur"]]
df["col_2"] = [pair[1] for pair in df["cur"]]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      cur
0  [2, 4]
1  [3, 4]
2  [1, 4]
3  [0, 0]
      cur  col1  col2
0  [2, 4]     2     4
1  [3, 4]     3     4
2  [1, 4]     1     4
3  [0, 0]     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `apply` and `pd.Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val1': [[2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 4], [0, 0]]})   

df['val1'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda x: x + 1).add_prefix('col_')
```

Output:

```
   col_1  col_2
0      2      4
1      3      4
2      1      4
3      0      0
```

Or similiar to @ALollz but more robust to capture any number of columns.

```
pd.DataFrame(df['val1'].tolist())\
  .rename(columns=lambda x: x + 1)\
  .add_prefix('col_')
```